# Carriage Return Line Break from MS Access into Adobe Acrobat

Tags: sql, ms-access, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am working on a MS access report, and am just in the final stages of tweaking it for aesthetic purposes. I am trying to get whitespace between paragraphs in the MS report, without producing funny characters when viewing in Adobe Acrobat.

Originally, I was just using the replace function to add two sets of `Chr(13) + Chr(10)` in each paragraph. This worked internally within MS Access, and also worked when viewing the produced PDF in Chrome browser. However, when viewing it in Adobe Acrobat, would produce a funny character `[?]`.

I have played around with various combinations of `Chr(10)`, `Chr(13)`, etc. to try and achieve a result that produces whitespace in both technologies and haven't found anything.

Things I have tried:

`Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)` (and the converse).
This resulted in the correct whitespace in Access and in Chrome, but strange symbol in Acrobat on the same line.

`Chr(10)`
This resulted in a new line, but no white space in all three technologies. (No funny characters).

`Chr(10) & Chr(10)`
This resulted in a new line and white space in Access. In Acrobat, this would add whitespace, but in that white space would the strange symbol appear.

`Chr(10) & Chr(32) & Chr(10)`
This resulted in a new line, but no white space in Access. In Acrobat, this would result in a new line with no white space, and the strange symbol would appear on top of the letters in the new line.

All help is appreaciated.

Comment: I tested this and don't get the 'funny' characters. Might have something to do with the font type used in report. Mine uses **Calibri (Detail)**. Also, displaying PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: @June7 My acrobat is using Calibri (embedded subset). My acrobat has no 'Content Editing' option in the properties for me to change the font either. When pasting into Notepad++, there is no characters except for CR LF either...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting changing font in Acrobat. I was referencing font used in Access report design. I did not mention 'Content Editing' - what is that?

Comment: @June7 oh my bad. The access font is the same Calibri (detail). Content Editing is how to change font in Acrobat - which I mistakenly thought you were referring. As far as I can tell, this isn't a font issue - I was thinking it might be Acrobat mistakenly interpreting multiple Ch(10)'s incorrectly. But even when adding a Chr(32) in between it still doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Since I cannot replicate issue, cannot offer solution. I am also still using Access 2010. You might try with a different computer and/or different report. What about display in Reader?